# How reproduced html_safe function in ruby (without rails)

Tags: ruby

In ruby (not in rails) i'm trying to get [html_safe](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) function as in rails.
My aims is to convert accent and space in %20, ... caractère

Is a regex available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that you need exactly `html_safe` since it only marks string as safe. Maybe this will do the work:

```
require 'cgi'
puts CGI.escape 'caractère+caractère'
```

Output:

```
caract%C3%A8re%2Bcaract%C3%A8re
```